# How to read data from an ESP32 to flutter app via bluetooth classic?

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, esp32, android-bluetooth

I am trying to build a display app for my college senior design project using flutter. The app needs to receive and display data from an ESP32 via bluetooth serial.

I found a few tutorials/examples related to this, but I haven't been able to get any of them to work. Most of the tutorials are from 2-3+ years ago and might be outdated. There are always dependency issues or other errors. I'm pretty new to flutter in general and would appreciate some guidance on bluetooth setup.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check
[ESP32 / atPlatform Step 8 - Sending & Receiving Data with a Flutter App (ESP32 & Flutter)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L24F-SwRC_s)